# Did Anthony Corleone play the same song as was played during the wedding scene of Apollonia and Michael?

Tags: the-godfather, the-godfather-3

I have watched both The Godfather and The Godfather part 2 many times but I am watching the third for the first time. I saw when Anthony played a "Authentic Sicilian" song for Michael , it reminded him of Apollonia and his eyes became wet. I went back to the scene in the first movie but could not make out whether the wedding band was playing the same song.

PS:- I have not read the books .

Comment: The Godfather 2 & 3 were not based on the book.

Comment: You recognize it as the theme music for all the Godfather movies, though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

Anthony sings "Brucia La Terra" which is not the same as any song played at Connie's wedding in *The Godfather*

"[Brucia la Terra](https://godfather.fandom.com/wiki/Brucia_La_Terra)" ("The Earth burns" or "The land burns") is a Sicilian ballad from the town of Corleone.

The song's lyrics were written by Giuseppe Rinaldi.

Comment: Isn't he asking about Michael's wedding, when he was in hiding in Italy, and not Connie's wedding?